# Why are the results of JavaScript query are always successful even when the user does not exist in the parse.com db?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com and the JavaScript SDK.

Purpose of code: Takes text input from a user and checks in the parse data browser if this name exists and then displays Matched or an error code.

At the moment the issue is that no matter what is typed into the input box, a "sucess" result is returned. This happens even when there is not a user with that name in the parse bata browser.

I'm not sure if its an issue with the equalTo line or the way the success function is working?

This is driving me nuts!

```
 query.equalTo("username",friendName);  // find users that match
```

If anyone from Parse.com reads this it would be nice if your forum was maintained, its awful customer support in general, which makes it hard to learn and progress

I'm reaching out for some help to either tweak the code or point out the error if there is one.

HTML

```
<form>
        <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
        <input type="text" id="friendsearch" placeholder="Find Friend" class="input-field" /> 
        <button id="find_button" type="button" class="btn btn-login">Find</button> 
</form>
```

JS/PARSE

```
 var friendName;


    function findFriend(){
       friendName = $('#friendsearch').val();
       console.log(friendName);

        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.equalTo("username",friendName);  // find users that match
        query.find({
        success: function(friend) {
        alert(friendName); 
        console.log("Matched"); 
          },
            error: function (error) {
         //Show if no user was found to match
         //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                console.log(("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message))

             }

        });   
    }

    $('#find_button').click(function(e){
        findFriend();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it should return an error? your query works fine, so the success callback will always called. You should instead handle the case of "match not found", inside the success callback, with something like this:

```
query.find({
        success: function(friendMatches) {

            // Query executed with success

            if (friendMatches.length == 0)
                alert('NO MATCH FOUND!!!');

        },
        error: function (error) {
         alert('query failed with error' + error.message);
        }
});
```

(**note**: in the success function,i've changed your "friend" parameter with "friendMatches", since it is an array of possible results, empty if no match is found)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to crack this for over a week!!

Comment: laco - thanks, quick question is there a } missing from the above? should it be just above }); at the base of the code?